# Get source of css-background-image loaded by url

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

Is this possible to **get** (not **load**) already loaded src(svg) of image from dom-element?

So I have smth like this:

`.icon{ background-image: url('some_link_to_svg') }`

`<span class="icon"></span>`

Im able to load svg text:

`url = getComputedStyle(<element>).backgroundImage.substring(5, url.length-2)`

`(await fetch(url)).text()`

But is this possible to get it w/o loading with already rendered image?? Somewhere browser saved it anyway for rendering

Comment: When an image is loaded into your browser, it will be stored in the cache under the URL. If you access that same URL, it will load from the cache instead of going over the internet a second time. So what you have should be just as fast. You can check this by using the Network tab of the Chrome Dev Tools. Just see if the image is downloaded more than once, and how long it takes each time.

Comment: Im agreed about caching, and using loading of cached so far - as a lack of other variants.
However still wonder how to get it without fetching